# Sprite_index is not set

Tags: sprite, game-engine, game-maker, gml

I'm following a YouTube tutorial on a fighting game. Facing an error:
`Var <unknown_object>.sprite_index not set.`
The error was here:

```
if (sprite_index != sprKill_foward)
{
    sprite_index = sprKill_foward;
    image_index = 0;
}
```

codes for the object:

```
switch (state)
{
    case 0:  //< idle
        UpdateMoveIdle();
        break;
    case 1: //< move fwd
        UpdateMoveFwd();
        break;
    case 2: //< move back
        UpdateMoveBack();
        break;
    default:
        show_debug_message("Error! Unknown state: " + string(state) + " Maybe you added a state but haven't updated the Update method.");
        break;
}

if (nextState != state)
{
    //change the state
    state = nextState;
            
    //execute the start function for the new state
    switch (state)
{
        case 0:  //< idle
            StartIdle();
            break;
        case 1: //< move fwd
            StartMoveFwd();
            break;
        case 2: //< move back
            StartMoveBack();
            break;
        default:
            show_debug_message("Error! Unknown state: " + string(state) + " Maybe you added a state but haven't updated the Start method.");
            break;
    }
}
```

I tried checking every syntax error and reviewing the tutorial but I can't identify the error.

Comment: You mention the error was "here", but did not specify where it happens.  It's possible through scripts that it can't find it's meant object. And just to make sure, the object does have a default sprite set?

Comment: yeah it's on the 'if (sprite_index != sprKill_foward)'
and I am not sure if it has default sprite set to be honest, I'm just following along with the tutorial on the video.

Comment: With "here", I meant the location where the code is placed. Because I think it should be within an Object's Event. But if it's outside that object, then it's trying to address the object through sprite_index. I also want to ensure that the object containing the code should be placed in a room for it to exist.

Answer (score 1):

If you are following an older tutorial in a recent GameMaker version, you will need to wrap the contents of the scripts inside a `function` - so if the script in the tutorial is

```
/// UpdateMoveIdle()
if (sprite_index != sprKill_foward)
{
    sprite_index = sprKill_foward;
    image_index = 0;
}
```

that would now be

```
function UpdateMoveIdle() {
    if (sprite_index != sprKill_foward)
    {
        sprite_index = sprKill_foward;
        image_index = 0;
    }
}
```

when you create a new script, there should be a comment inside with a link to a help page explaining the changes.